# i had problem with tkinter def not starting

Tags: python, tkinter

I made facebook script when I run and press on start button I'm getting this error I made this GUI interface with Tkinter and I'm using python 3 my error is when I click on start button he is not starting google chrome and when I disable Tkinter and work through command line he works correctly you can see error screen shot:

[image]

```
import pyautogui as pg
import time
from selenium import webdriver
from getpass import getpass
from tkinter import *

window = Tk()
window.title('Facebook Sharing')
text = Label(window, text='Facebook Sharing Script', font="Source_Sans_Pro 20 bold")
text.pack()
frame = Frame(window)
frame.pack()

one = Frame(window)
one.pack( side = TOP )

frontframe = Frame(window)
frontframe.pack( side = TOP )


bottomframe = Frame(window)
bottomframe.pack( side = TOP )

lastframe = Frame(window)
lastframe.pack( side = TOP )

last = Frame(window)
last.pack( side = TOP )

Lable1 = Label(frame, text="Enter Your UserName!    ", font='Source_Sans_Pro 11')
Lable1.pack( side = LEFT)
user_name = Entry(frame, bd =5)
user_name.pack(side = RIGHT)

Lable2 = Label(frontframe, text="Enter Your Passowrd!     ", font='Source_Sans_Pro 11')
Lable2.pack( side = LEFT)
Password = Entry(frontframe, bd =5)
Password.pack(side = RIGHT)

Lable3 = Label(bottomframe, text="Enter Your Description!   ", font='Source_Sans_Pro 11')
Lable3.pack( side = LEFT)
description = Entry(bottomframe, bd =5)
description.pack(side = RIGHT)

Lable4 = Label(lastframe, text="Enter Your Keyword!       ", font='Source_Sans_Pro 11')
Lable4.pack( side = LEFT)
keyword = Entry(lastframe, bd =5)
keyword.pack(side = RIGHT)

Lable5 = Label(one, text="Enter Your Post Url!         ", font='Source_Sans_Pro 11')
Lable5.pack( side = LEFT)
post_url = Entry(one, bd =5)
post_url.pack(side = RIGHT)

Button_Start = Button(last, text="Start", fg="black", width=50, command=all)
Button_Start.pack( side = BOTTOM)


pg.FAILSAFE = True

#this is hidden def
def all():

print("Done")
window.mainloop()
```

Error!

```
Exception in Tkinter callback
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\User`enter code here`s\Hamza Lachi\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 1705, in __call__
    return self.func(*args)
TypeError: all() takes exactly one argument (0 given)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So `All()` is native Python function, you can read more about it in the follow link  [all(iterable)](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#all), that's the problem, the Python is calling the his native function instead of the function you created.

[image]

You can solve this changing the name of your function.

Read more about it:

- [Built-in Functions](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html)
- [List of Keywords in Python](https://www.programiz.com/python-programming/keyword-list)

Comment: correct! it is crucial to name your functions and variables with unique and meaningful names!

Comment: File ".\All.py", line 55, in <module>
    Button_Start = Button(last, text="Start", fg="black", width=50, command=hi)
NameError: name 'hi' is not defined

Comment: You're welcome! You must put your function `hi()` before the `Button_Start`.

Comment: Friend! be careful when you are creating modules and functions, the name is important, don't create functions and modules with the same name of native Python functions and modules, because it may have conflict.